# signalr ondisconnected not firing

Tags: c#, signalr

I have the below code on my hub that is supposed to update a flag on my db if there is a disconnection.  When debugging in VS2017 I can see it works okay and the event is hit when closing the page.  But when using on my client I try to simulate a disconnection by "pulling the cable" but no flag update.
I can see from the console logs on the browser the client IS disconnected from the hub (after 30s).
Can anyone suggest what could be the issue.  I'm using the recent version of signalR from nuget

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    DeleteConnectiondb(connectionId);
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}

public String DeleteConnectiondb(string connectionid)
{
    String IPRadionConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbIPRadioConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection IPdatabaseConn = new MySqlConnection(IPRadionConnectionString))
        {
            IPdatabaseConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySQLcommandUpdate = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tblRegistrations SET " + "active='0' " + "WHERE " + "connectionid=@connectionid", IPdatabaseConn);
            mySQLcommandUpdate.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@connectionid", connectionid));
            using (MySqlDataReader myReader1 = mySQLcommandUpdate.ExecuteReader())
            {
                myReader1.Close();
            }

            IPdatabaseConn.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: found this - "If your web servers stop working or the application restarts, the OnDisconnected method is not called. Therefore, it is possible that your data repository will have records for connection ids that are no longer valid" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections